# How to import products data in Sylius ..?

Tags: php, symfony, sylius, akeneo

Hello i am using **Sylius 1.0.4** and **Symfony 3.3.13**

i want to *import products data* form my old database to new sylius database by CSV/Excel

Answer (score 0):

you cant take a look here:

https://github.com/FriendsOfSylius/SyliusImportExportPlugin

or maybe try to do some custom operations. It does not come out of the box with sylius. Good luck!